# UIimage to char* conversion

Tags: ios, ipad, tiff

I am trying to convert uiimage to char array to use with libtiff.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the easiest way that I know of to get the bytes of a UIImage:

```
UIImage *someImage = ...;
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(someImage.CGImage));
const UInt8 *data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
```

Data then is an array of bytes.

EDIT:

Here is how you get an char array:

```
const unsigned char * buffer =  CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
```

EDIT 2:

Try casting it to char:

```
char * buffer = (char *)CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is a uInt right not char array.  I am getting an error in  TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(image, 0, buffer, 25 * 144);  buffer should be char*.

Comment: Don't forget to call `CFRelease(pixelData)` after you're done with it.

Comment: It does not work yet I get the error  as "No matching function call to TIFFWriteEncodedStrip"

Comment: You'll have to import the appropriate header or something.

Comment: I tried checking that when I declare buffer this way: char buffer[] ={}; it does nt show any error when I use this const unsigned char * buffer I get the error. I did not really understand reason??

Comment: I am sorry could you please explain more clearly. I could nt get you.

Comment: This question has actually been answered. You should technically be asking another question. Try this instead: char * buffer =  CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

Comment: I have edited the question to show the error i get when I use this char * buffer = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);. I don't mind asking a new question,But can u help how to convert the uiimage to the char buffer used in tifflib.

Comment: I have one last question in this topic. I will post it as a new question please help with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233282/convert-tiff-data-type-in-libtiff-to-nsdata-ios

Comment: @JeshuaLacock - I tried your answer but used the const unsigned char * buffer = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData); statement and it return an empty string.  Is there a step between the CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(someImage.CGImage)); statement and the const unsigned char * buffer =  CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData); char array statement that I am missing?