# Convert Tiff data type in libTiff to nsdata ios

Tags: ios, ipad, tiff

I am using libtiff to create tif images. Can any one help how to convert TIFF back to nsdata.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you're looking to do?
NSData *data = (NSData *)CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(
                            NULL, image, sizeof(TIFF), kCFAllocatorNull);

Comment: But I get an error when using Sizeof function

Comment: I think CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy is what to be used but I am messing up with parameters do you have any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help by the community.

I figured out the answer. Just use the same function. that's it. It did not flash to me until now.

Answer (score 0):

Conveniently, CFData is toll-free bridged with NSData, so you can basically turn it directly into an NSData object without doing anything. Just replace the line

```
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

With

```
NSData *tiffData = CFBridgingRelease(pixelData);
```

And that's your tiffData as an autoreleased NSData object, ready to use as you wish.

Comment: I am trying to convert image variable to nsdata not pixelData variable

Comment: This is not working. My app is crashing when executing NSData *tiffData = CFBridgingRelease(pixelData);

Comment: What's the crash? Did you get rid of the CFRelease? You don't need both.

Comment: I did get rid of CFRelease(pixelData); I only see program received signal:"EXC_BAD_ACCESS". nothing appears in the log. I have updated the code changes I have mde