# Objective c UIImage to char* conversion returning empty string

Tags: objective-c, c, uiimage, objective-c++

I am trying to convert a **UIImage** (src) into a **const unsigned char ***

I found a great example [as an answer on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217455/1735836).  I followed the example but my buffer is an empty string ("").  I've been looking for more information but cannot find any.

Here is my code:

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(src.CGImage));
const unsigned char *buffer = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);  // buffer is ""
CFIndex bufferSize = CFDataGetLength(pixelData);
```

Is there an interim step I am missing or should I be using a different method all together?

Here is an image of my erroneous code:

[image]

It doesn't matter if I try to convert using CDDataRef or NSData I still get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to copy the const unsigned char * into the unsigned char *.

Comment: This question is tagged both `c++` and `objective-c` -- is it really Objective-C++? Because that would change things.

Comment: OK.  I added Objective-C++.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: there's actually no C++ here (except `nullptr`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you aren't `malloc`ing your imageBuffer - the debugger saying `address = 0x0` makes it obvious.

To fix, just malloc imageBuffer:

```
imageBuffer = malloc(bufferSize);
```

Because you said this is Objective-C++, you'll need to cast the `malloc` -

```
imageBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(bufferSize);
```

Put this before your `memcpy`.

Good luck!

Comment: Side note - this only fixes the screenshot example. I don't know how to fix your first bit of code off the top of my head.